Generalize knowledge across multiple documents
I created a chat via platform.openai.com. It uses GPT-4 turbo preview. I have uploaded multiple documents to it. The knowledge is scattered across different docs.
The behavior I get is the assistant answers questions based on doc chunks. It does not connect dots between docs, which renders it almost completely useless in my use case.
Is there an easy way to improve upon it? I want to ask questions like “Based on the reference document, what are the mentions of terms from it in the remaining docs?”.

You may find Graph Query Language relevant in this case. Neo4J is the gold standard for GraphQL. You can also get the fundamentals of it from their free courses here. GraphQL can help you for grounding LLM and make the scattered knowledges across different documents to work together. This represents the data as nodes and their relationships with edges. So, the main benefit of it is to allow you to ask questions which are not directly written anywhere in the documents. For example, for a short document you may end up having a graph like the following:

(Image Credit: https://towardsdatascience.com/integrate-llm-workflows-with-knowledge-graph-using-neo4j-and-apoc-27ef7e9900a2)
Now from the data it is possible to make a query to find the movies where both Keanu Reeves and Carrie-Anne Moss acted in. Now this information may not be directly written in the available documents. But even after that we can literally create insights/knowledges like this.
The steps of transforming your Knowledgebase to an interrelated graph representation are as follows (simplified):
Training

Chunking Documents
Pass each chunk to LLM to form a triplet. From a single chunk multiple triplets can be formed based on the available information. Triplets are nothing but 3-tuples, i.e., (subject, relationship, object). For example: (Keanu Reeves, ACTED_IN, The Matrix Reloaded), (Lily Wachowski, DIRECTED, The Matrix Reloaded) etc.
These triplets will be saved in the graph database. Where the subjects and objects are the nodes, and the relationships are the edges.

Inference

During inference, the user query will be converted to a graph query provided the schema of the graph with the help of LLM.
The query will be used to retrieve the relevant results from the database.
The resultant data will again be converted back to Natural Language with the help of LLM.

More

GraphQL like Neo4J supports indexing, including vector indexing, which will allow you not only direct-match search but also vector embedding search in the database.
It also supports keyword-based indexing, and you can even use it along with vector embedding indexing.
Popular frameworks like LangChain has a built-in integration support for this. And this is for Llama-Index library.
Supports building graph from other databases like MySQL. So, this will help you to create a holistic representation of all data of your domain.

Considerations

There is no silver bullet that can work in all scenarios.
The GraphQL also has some problems, the obvious problems are the overheads of creating graph database, converting from Natural Language to GraphQL and vice-versa.
The generated query may become invalid and may not retrieve anything.
The generated query may be valid, but the constant values may not be directly present in the database, and eventually you may end up having nothing. For example, when the generated query contains spelling mistakes/synonym of the term you are looking for from the database.
The context size may not allow you to create appropriate tuple if the related terms are far apart.
There can be multiple almost similar triplets be generated which could have been reduced to a single triplet.
As far as I know, Neo4J Community Edition can have exactly one standard database. To create more than one database you may need to use the paid version. The community version also lacks additional security features.

